# Google Dataflow workers hanging at 99% completion

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, distributed-system

I have been blocked by this problem for over a week. When I run the following pipeline, my workers churn their way through my data - right up until the 99% mark, on which they hang indefinitely. I cannot think of a simple solution that doesn't involve a large amount of engineering to get around this. I also have no way of knowing the cause, as my application logs show that the last input passed to the straggling worker was transformed successfully (so it isn't hanging in the middle of a map).

If I had a way to add a timeout to the job as a whole, I could kill those hanging workers and finish off the pipeline with what I have. Unfortunately, python's timeout libraries are extremely fragile (can't use signal, func_timeout only works when not nested, can't fork another process, etc.).

Straggling workers:
[Straggling workers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sKbF.png)

Pipeline stages:
[pipeline stages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3reD.png)

Impact on affected pipeline stage:
[impact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWle0.png) - Notice that my job should have ended when the throughput dropped, as it was effectively 99.9% complete. However, I was billed for the time that the workers were spinning.

Note that the "train" stage is processing an order of magnitude more data.

### Attempted fixes

- Adding a timeout to my processing function

  - Improved my throughput, but the problem still persisted

I believe that the cause is from some lightning-strike bug on Dataflow's end killing my pipeline (could be due to anything - resource starvation, deadlock during work stealing, network drop, etc.). Therefore, I am more interested in figuring out how to make my pipeline robust against these issues, rather than have to anticipate/prevent all of them.

### Pipeline code

(Copied 3 times - `Train`/`Val`/`Test`)

```
"ReadFromText" >> beam.io.ReadFromText(file_pattern=data_path)
| "Shuffle0" >> beam.Reshuffle()
| "Convert" >> beam.FlatMap(map_fn)
| "Shuffle1" >> beam.Reshuffle()
| "Write" >> beam.io.WriteToTFRecord(
    output_path,
    coder=beam.coders.ProtoCoder(tf.train.Example)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is probably in the pipeline.

The convert step in [the pipeline shown in the middle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3reD.png) is using 2 days of wall time, compared to a few hours for the other two pipelines. What's different in that step? The convert step is slow for whatever reason. A possibility could be memory problems. Have a look at the memory and CPU charts of the job. If you see a "peaky" pattern (constantly going up and down), that could be an indicator of memory issues (confirm it by inspecting the worker logs).

If you are having memory issues, I would try to use [Dataflow Prime](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/enable-dataflow-prime) (vertical autoscaling when there are memory issues) or maybe a regular Dataflow job with highmem workers (but Dataflow Prime will probably do a better job right fitting the resources required for each step).

But it could be perfectly that your convert step is just slow. If the implementation can parallelize on the data processed, it should be fine and should not require vertical scalability. But depending on what step is doing, it may not be possible to implement in a parallelizable way.